# iOS app crash on apple review only, work fine with adhoc test with device

Tags: ios

i got rejected from apple review team today for app crash on launch.

But I have no problems with adhoc version with same circumstance. 
I have tested with ios7.0.4 and it never crashed while app launching.

Any chance to let me know what the problem is??

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a5591fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a5c0a4f pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a50a029 abort + 73
3   myapps                      0x01930ff0 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 312
4   myapps                      0x01920960 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 256
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3a5bb721 _sigtramp + 41
6   myapps                      0x013bc604 UnitySendMessage (WebScripting.cpp:135)
7   myapps                      0x013bc604 UnitySendMessage (WebScripting.cpp:135)
8   myapps                      0x0033a128 m_3b8f + 52
9   myapps                      0x0019195c m_1824 + 120
10  myapps                      0x0123550c m_wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
11  myapps                      0x01920204 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 2152
12  myapps                      0x019c2254 mono_runtime_invoke + 132
13  myapps                      0x014dcf30 scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethod*, MonoObject*, ScriptingArguments&, MonoException**) (ScriptingBackendApi_Mono.cpp:183)
14  myapps                      0x0156e75c ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(MonoException**, bool) (ScriptingInvocation.cpp:113)
15  myapps                      0x0156e728 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(MonoException**) (ScriptingInvocation.cpp:98)
16  myapps                      0x0156edd8 ScriptingInvocationNoArgs::InvokeChecked() (ScriptingInvocationNoArgs.cpp:79)
17  myapps                      0x015642dc MonoBehaviour::CallMethodInactive(ScriptingMethod*) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:345)
18  myapps                      0x01565fa4 MonoBehaviour::CallAwake() (MonoBehaviour.cpp:1393)
19  myapps                      0x015661e4 MonoBehaviour::AddToManager() (MonoBehaviour.cpp:1488)
20  myapps                      0x014c4f3c Behaviour::UpdateEnabledState(bool) (Behaviour.cpp:47)
21  myapps                      0x014c4f98 Behaviour::AwakeFromLoad(AwakeFromLoadMode) (Behaviour.cpp:54)
22  myapps                      0x01565f6c MonoBehaviour::AwakeFromLoad(AwakeFromLoadMode) (MonoBehaviour.cpp:1383)
23  myapps                      0x0158a820 AwakeFromLoadQueue::InvokePersistentManagerAwake(AwakeFromLoadQueue::Item*, unsigned int, AwakeFromLoadMode, void (*)(Object&, TypeTree const&)) (AwakeFromLoadQueue.cpp:326)
24  myapps                      0x0158a79c AwakeFromLoadQueue::PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad(int, AwakeFromLoadMode, void (*)(Object&, TypeTree const&)) (AwakeFromLoadQueue.cpp:201)
25  myapps                      0x0158a6e0 AwakeFromLoadQueue::PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad(AwakeFromLoadMode, void (*)(Object&, TypeTree const&)) (AwakeFromLoadQueue.cpp:160)
26  myapps                      0x0158dc34 PersistentManager::IntegrateAllThreadedObjectsStep2(AwakeFromLoadQueue&) (PersistentManager.cpp:1004)
27  myapps                      0x015502a8 CompleteAwakeSequence (SaveAndLoadHelper.cpp:778)
28  myapps                      0x0155038c CompletePreloadManagerLoadLevel(std::string const&, AwakeFromLoadQueue&) (SaveAndLoadHelper.cpp:758)
29  myapps                      0x01542288 LevelLoading::LoadLevel(int, std::string const&, AwakeFromLoadQueue&) (Player.cpp:1354)
30  myapps                      0x01542068 PlayerLoadLevelFromThread(int, std::string const&, AwakeFromLoadQueue&) (Player.cpp:371)
31  myapps                      0x01544d0c PreloadLevelOperation::IntegrateMainThread() (PreloadManager.cpp:779)
32  myapps                      0x01544170 PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(bool) (PreloadManager.cpp:467)
33  myapps                      0x01544570 PreloadManager::WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete() (PreloadManager.cpp:531)
34  myapps                      0x01544658 PreloadManager::UpdatePreloading() (PreloadManager.cpp:554)
35  myapps                      0x01542ef0 PlayerLoop(bool, bool, IHookEvent*) (Player.cpp:1762)
36  myapps                      0x0138998c UnityPlayerLoop (LibEntryPoint.mm:182)
37  myapps                      0x0137c714 -[UnityAppController repaintDisplayLink] (UnityAppController.mm:221)
38  QuartzCore                      0x320a3acf CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 95
39  QuartzCore                      0x320a3879 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 341
40  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x34ccd76b IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 103
41  IOKit                           0x3092abe3 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 247
42  CoreFoundation                  0x2fc08b7f __CFMachPortPerform + 135
43  CoreFoundation                  0x2fc13775 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 33
44  CoreFoundation                  0x2fc1370f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 343
45  CoreFoundation                  0x2fc11edb __CFRunLoopRun + 1403
46  CoreFoundation                  0x2fb7c46d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
47  CoreFoundation                  0x2fb7c24f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
48  GraphicsServices                0x348b02e7 GSEventRunModal + 135
49  UIKit                           0x32431841 UIApplicationMain + 1133
50  myapps                      0x00014b6c main (main.mm:28)
51  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a4a2ab5 start + 1
```

Comment: paste the code which is giving this error

Answer (score 0):

You are using Unity to create an iOS App. Unity 4.3 has fixed several issues with scrolling and some other memory issues. See the details on

http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-4.3